# Toroidal magnet in Tonomura et al. demonstration of Aharonov-Bohm effect

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, superconductivity

What does the magnetic field look like in Tonomura's toroidal magnet coated with a superconductor?

[image: Tonomura's toroidal magnet coated with a superconductor]

See [this paper to find results showing conclusive proof of the A-B effect and flux quantization](http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.56.792).

Context: For the A-B effect to work, there needs to be a magnetic flux in the area between the alternate paths which will produce the interference fringe patterns (but not necessarily along the paths themselves). The paper shows fringe patterns due to interference between the center of the toroid and outside the toroid, which means that there needs to be a flux in the plane of the toroid for A-B effect to be observed. Doesn't the superconductor coating quantize the flux penetrating the center of the toroid rather than the in-plane flux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful, the superconductor was used in the Tonomura's experiment to *shield* the magnetic field, thus to prove a part of the Aharonov-Bohm effect: namely that you do not need a magnetic field interacting with the electrons to observe the interference fringes, a non-trivial gauge potential is sufficient. Thanks to the Meißner effect, the magnetic field does not penetrate the superconductor, and never reach the permalloy inside the superconducting shield.

Then in the experiment, **they record the current inside the permalloy**, which is *not* superconducting.

To record the flux quantisation, you would have measured the current flowing inside the superconductor, which I think they never did. The quantisation of the flux for a multiply connected superconductor is recorded in the Little-Parks experiment, an older experiment made in the 60's. It consists in an oscillation pattern of the critical temperature due to the magnetic flux piercing the hole inside the superconductor.

To answer your first question: the magnetic field looks pretty much like the proposal of the Aharonov-Bohm effect: it is constant inside the ring and zero in the ring and outside the ring (see figure below). Actually, due to experimental limitations, it was never sure whether there was a magnetic flux outside the ring in the experiment done before this one. Here it is the same thing in principle: a tiny amount of flux may persist outside the ring. Nevertheless, thanks to the superconductor shield, there is no magnetic field in the permalloy in the Tonomura's experiment, and so the demonstration of the Aharonov-Bohm was for the first time convincing in this setup.

[image: Aharonov-Bohm description in term of the magnetic field, which is zero outside the normal metal and constant inside.]

Comment: "it is constant inside the ring and zero in the ring and outside the ring" what do you mean by this?

Comment: @eqb Of course if you never heard about AB effect I understand a bit more you question... I added a figure, and suggest you to check the original paper as well. The AB effect is an effect of the flux, neither of the magnetic field nor magnetic (vector-) potential. Then, AB show that even in region where $B=0$ but $A\neq 0$ you can in principle have a flux, and there are interference pattern when electrons paths enclose the flux even if the electron never feel the magnetic field (so they travel in the region where $B=0$). Check SE-physics as well to find good discussion about it as well.

Comment: Thanks for that picture. I think I now know what you mean by "constant inside the ring and zero in the ring and outside the ring." The fringe patterns are a result of interference of the electrons taking the alternate paths -- so where are the electrons and what is their direction of motion here?

Comment: Mayhaps a glance at this article http://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.115.485 should be a prerequisite for asking question about the the Aharonov-Bohm effect, as I said in my previous comment. The article is free to download from the APS web-site.